# How to pull Vcenter overall stats using api

Tags: api, vmware, vcenter

i am trying to pull the below stats using the vmware vsphere api but cant seem to pull these in particular. I can pull stats for hosts, vm and storage pools but not the overall vcenter.

[VCenter overall stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcj2g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Those metrics are available in a separate API endpoint that is related to the vCenter appliance itself and can be found in the Health service: https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/appliance/health/

Comment: those endpoints only return the status colour, im looking for the actual values so free memory, cpu and storage